# Using MAX 9814 PCM data to create a .WAV file

Tags: wav, micropython, pcm, raspberry-pi-pico, adc

I have a MAX 9814 microphone/amplifier attached through ADC to my Raspberry Pi Pico WH. I am trying to get it record audio (specifically into a .wav file). I am struggling to understand the digital information that microphone is sending me, and would appreciate help on analyzing what I believe to be PCM values.

BTW: I am sending these raw values from the Pi Pico to my computer in real-time through serial port connection, so there is a lot more computing power that I can work with to process this data.

Here is the script on my Pi Pico (I've taken out the serial port connection stuff since it works fine)

```
import machine
from machine import ADC, Pin
import time
import uos

baseline = 0 
variability = 0.5 
SAMPLES_PER_SECOND = 44100

soundSensor = ADC(28) # Pin where sensor device (Microphone) is connected
led = Pin('LED', Pin.OUT)

while True:
    start_time = time.ticks_ms()
    
    print(soundSensor.read_u16())
    
    # If we detect a spike in the waveform greater than a 10% deviation from our baseline, someone is probably talking.
    if soundSensor.read_u16() > (baseline + baseline*variability) or soundSensor.read_u16() < (baseline - baseline*variability):
        led.on() # Turn the light on if we're detecting a spike
    else:
        led.off() # Otherwise, keep the light off
    
    elapsed_time = time.ticks_diff(time.ticks_ms(), start_time)
    expected_interval = int(1000 / SAMPLES_PER_SECOND)  # Convert to integer
    sleep_time = max(0, expected_interval - elapsed_time)  # Adjusted sleep time to maintain desired sample rate

    time.sleep_ms(sleep_time)
```

Here is the script on my computer:

```
import wave 
from pathlib import Path

def read_microphone_output(file_name):
    p = Path(__file__).with_name(file_name)

    with open(p.absolute(), 'rb') as pcmfile:
        pcmdata = pcmfile.read()
    with wave.open('store_info.wav', 'wb') as wavfile:
        wavfile.setparams((1, 2, 44100, 0, 'NONE', 'NONE'))
        wavfile.writeframes(pcmdata)

read_microphone_output("store_info.txt")
```

Here is an example of what "store_info.txt" looks like:

```
26342
25910
25382
25798
26278
26022
```

"store_info.wav" comes out as just a high pitched buzzing sound that lasts for about a second (keep in mind that I sample 10 seconds of microphone data, so the audio file should last for 10 seconds).

I am hoping for "store_info.wav" to come out as an audio recording--if I speak into it, I can hear my own voice.

Comment: _"what I believe to be PCM values."_ - perhaps you believe wrongly. You won't get far if you're working under a misapprehension.The ADC data sheet should tell you exactly what you're getting.

Comment: What you convert from an audio signal via an ADC is not PCM, it just the digital representation of that analog data at a particular time. The ADC output needs to be feed into an I2S peripheral in order to generate the PCM output. The PCM output then needs to be converted to .wav format in order to save it to file.